# Drop-Down Combo-box in HTML (with Javascript or JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I've seen this question many times online, but none of them really have what I need.

Is there any available *multi-select drop-down combo-box* written in Javascript available, so that I can avoid reinventing the wheel?
(I'm still learning web programming, so I'm not too comfortable with making my own pop-ups yet...)

What I need is pretty much [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dropdown-check-list):

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/demo.png))</sub>

However, this one has several flaws:

- The latest version doesn't seem to have the button on the side
- The width grows arbitrarily big, or remains a fixed size (I need a "maximum width" option)
- *The control should look **native*** in the browser, not custom-made. The arrow here is just a PNG file, and it pays no attention to what the browser actually displays for a regular combo-box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/select-box) available which I think you're already aware of. <strike>However, I'm not sure if there is a way to detect how the browser renders it actually.</strike>

Even in IE/XP, there's no *easy* way to tell if Visual styles are turned off or not (other than hacks like scrollbar width calculation etc).

Found one that claims to have native look and feel (not sure if you can do checkboxes in options): http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/2009/07/16/simple-combo-box-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but is that one multi-select?

Comment: It has multiple select but not in a combo I guess. So far, I haven't found anything that gives you the native look and feel and allows multiple selects. I'm starting to feel that you might have to combine 2 different solutions to get what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it has multiselect"... are you referring to the plain old `<select multiple>` element? What I see on that site seems to be the exact same thing as this...

Comment: Also, in your original plugin, you may get a quick workaround by doing a browser detection and rendering a different image for the browser. Even XP's visual style can be detected via script so I guess that would be your easiest bet right now.

Comment: I know. I couldn't find anything else though. Sorry!